# Why one AWS EC2 instance usage is more than 24 hours per day and how to solve this?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS Free Tier. I run only one EC2 t2.micro instance. But the report tell me that the usage is more than 24 hours per day. That mean at the end of the month I will be charged (It estimate the total usage will be 1200 hours, larger than the limit 750 hours).

I can not figure out the problem.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible causes for this that come to mind:

- Check *all* the regions in the console to ensure that you didn't launch another machine in another region at some point.
- If you are starting and stopping the instance really often, which should be unnecessary, you will be billed more than one hour per hour.  For each hour an instance is running, you will be charged up to one additional hour for each stop/start, depending on the timing, because stopping an instance restarts the "instance-hour" timer and there is a minimum one hour charge for each "start."